# Matrix Derivatives for MLE estimates

Tags: calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I'm reading Tipping and Bishop's [paper](https://rss.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/1467-9868.00196) on Probabilistic Pricipal Component Analysis. To get the MLE estimate (variables $W \in \Re^{d \times q}$ and $\sigma^2 \in \Re^+$). $N, d , q \in \Re$ and $S \in 
\Re^{d \times d}$ is the Sample Covaraice Matrix, are constants.

$$\mathcal{L} = \frac{N}{2}\{d  \ln(2\pi) + \ln(|C|) + tr(C^{-1}S)\}$$
$$\text{where } C = WW^T + \sigma^2I$$
They set,
$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial W} = 0$$
and obtain eqn $(10)$ on page $619$, stating some "standard matrix calculus" results were used. I couldn't find any "direct" results in [this](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) book. Can someone please point me to a relevant resource, for this heavy Matrix Calculus.

Comment: Read “Matrix Algebra” by Abadir and Magnus , it’s a truly great book

Comment: Hints: Apply [Jacobi's formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula) to the log-det term and
$\Big[dC^{-1} = -C^{-1}\,dC\:C^{-1}\Big]$ to the last term. Both formulas are in the Matrix Cookbook.

Comment: @greg I want the derivative w.r.t $W$ How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Formulas (57) and (63) from the 'Cookbook' gives you the matrix derivative of $\operatorname{logdet}(\mathbf{C})$ and $\operatorname{tr}(\mathbf{C}^{-1} \mathbf{S})$

Using the fact that matrices are symmetric, this yields the differential
\begin{eqnarray}
d\phi
&=&
-\frac{N}{2}
\left[
\mathbf{C}^{-1}
- \mathbf{C}^{-1} \mathbf{S} \mathbf{C}^{-1} 
\right]
:
d\mathbf{C} \\
&=&
N
\left[
\mathbf{C}^{-1} \mathbf{S} \mathbf{C}^{-1} -
\mathbf{C}^{-1}
\right]\mathbf{W}
:
d\mathbf{W}
\end{eqnarray}
where the symbol $:$ stands for the Frobenius inner product.

UPDATE: By definition, $\mathbf{C}=
\mathbf{W}\mathbf{W}^T+\sigma^2 \mathbf{I}$.
We obtain the relation
$
d\mathbf{C}=
2(d\mathbf{W})\mathbf{W}^T
$.
The passage to the second line uses the useful property of the Frobenius inner product
$\mathbf{A}:\mathbf{B}\mathbf{C}^T
=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{C}:\mathbf{B}$.

Finally the gradient is
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \mathbf{W}}
= 
N
\left[
\mathbf{C}^{-1} \mathbf{S} \mathbf{C}^{-1} -
\mathbf{C}^{-1}
\right]\mathbf{W}
$$

Comment: How do we go from $dC$ to $dW$. Can you share a resource for this "chain rule".

Comment: See my update. We use here mostly trace properties.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to do tha math. Can you check if $dC = 2(dW)W^T$ is correct? I believe $dC = (dW)W^T + W (dW)^T$ but we later use the property A is symmetric implies $A : B + B^T = 2 (A : B)$. Which can again be derived using trace

Comment: You are perfectly correct.  was a little bit sloppy here with my notations. Because of the symmetry of the left hand side, simplifications occur again as you remarked.